# Where can I find a copy of this paper of Chowla and Vijayaraghavan?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, paper-request

Does anyone know where I can find a copy of Chowla and Vijayaraghavan's paper, '*'On the largest prime divisors of numbers''*?

The relevant literature say it was published in the Journal of the Indian Mathematical Society (1937), but one can't read it from there, as far as I know.

Comment: http://informaticsjournals.com/index.php/jims/article/view/17102  --- but one has to pay for the article, it is not a free download (and therefore I presume cannot be distributed freely from MO).

Comment: Why don't you try to borrow from your local library the relevant volume of "The collected papers of Sarvadaman Chowla"?